# AngularJS: Uncaught Error: No module: GridCambiable

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am trying to follow up a tutorial and demo that I found here http://jsfiddle.net/scyrizales/pC9dH/

As a result this is the code snippet of what I have done

```
<div ng-app="GridCambiable" ng-controller="GridCambiableController">

    <div class="bar">

        <!-- These two buttons switch the layout varaible,
             which causes the correct UL to be shown. -->

        <a class="list-icon" ng-class="{active: isLayout('list')}" ng-click="setLayout('list')"></a>
        <a class="grid-icon" ng-class="{active: isLayout('grid')}" ng-click="setLayout('grid')"></a>
    </div>

    <!-- We have two layouts. We choose which one to show depending on the "layout" binding -->

    <ul ng-show="isLayout('grid')" class="grid">
        <!-- A view with big photos and no text -->
        <li ng-repeat="p in pics">
            <a href="{{p.link}}" target="_blank"><img ng-src="{{p.images.low_resolution.url}}" /></a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <ul ng-show="isLayout('list')" class="list">
        <!-- A compact view smaller photos and titles -->
        <li ng-repeat="p in pics">
            <a href="{{p.link}}" target="_blank"><img ng-src="{{p.images.thumbnail.url}}" /></a>
            <p>{{p.caption.text}}</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

```
app.controller('GridCambiableController', ['$scope', 'instagram' ,
function ($scope, instagram){

    // Layout por defecto

    $scope.layout = 'grid';

    $scope.setLayout = function(layout){
        $scope.layout = layout;
    };

    $scope.isLayout = function(layout){
        return $scope.layout == layout;
    };
```

When I launch the code, I get this error on my chrome console

```
Uncaught Error: No module: GridCambiable
```

I have made a plunk of my attempt 
http://plnkr.co/edit/9BYKw45ZrIgVpbixRsAz?p=preview

Please why am I getting this on my console.
Thanks.

Comment: In your plunker add `app.js` in `index.html`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't include your `script.js` after you include `angular.min.js`

In your index.html:

```
<!--include angular-->
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is as per your plunker.

Answer (score 0):

add this before your controller:

var app = angular.module("GridCambiable", []);

Alternative:

angular.module("GridCambiable", []).controller('GridCambiableController', ['$scope', 'instagram' ,
function ($scope, instagram){

```
// Layout por defecto

$scope.layout = 'grid';

$scope.setLayout = function(layout){
    $scope.layout = layout;
};

$scope.isLayout = function(layout){
    return $scope.layout == layout;
};
```

Comment: Did you take a look at my controller?

Comment: you must create a angular app instance!  to create an app instance add :  var app = angular.module("GridCambiable", []);